# CryptoLicensing - Connecting to the service using Hostname

Tags: .net, components, cryptolicensing

I have tried contacting tech support with this question, but it has been over three weeks since they said they would look into it. Perhaps someone has had (and solved) a similar issue:

I'm having a problem trying to connect to the (customer deployed) license service using the hostname instead of the IP address. 
This would allow everything to keep running in case the IP of the server is changed.
I generated the customer deployed service for `http://HOSTNAME:8081/` and tried connecting using this URL.
When pinging the license service, the following exception is returned:

```
License not valid for running license server. 
ALLOWED: = http://HOSTNAME:8081/ , http://fe80::21d7:f28f:a8b2:6542%10 , http://fe80::2cf3:1cea:3f57:1fd%12 , http://192.168.254.2 , http://2001:0:5ef5:79fd:2cf3:1cea:3f57:1fd , 
REQUESTED: http://[fe80::21d7:f28f:a8b2:6542%10]:8081/Service.asmx/PingLicenseService
```

Contacting the service through the URL with hostname seems to automatically use the (first?) IPv6 address, enclosed in square brackets (as it should, otherwise it can’t figure out the port number).
The allowed URLs however, contain IPv6 addresses without these square brackets. 
Is this some kind of bug? (The port numbers seem to be missing as well.)

I tried getting the IPv4 address from the host name manually at runtime, but then I get:
The remote server returned an error: `(400) Bad Request`.

When I try browsing to the service using the IPv4 or IPv6 address myself (in a browser), the error is expanded to:

```
HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.
```

Which is also strange, since they are included in the allowed URLs. It seems only the URL in ServerSettings.xml is valid, where I have `http://HOSTNAME:8081/`. When I change the address in ServerSettings.xml to the IPv4 address again, I can connect from the software using the hostname or the IPv4 address.

Is it possible to prevent the customer from having to edit the ServerSettings.xml every time the server IP changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newest version of [CryptoLicensing](http://www.ssware.com/cryptolicensing/cryptolicensing_net.htm) - **v2012** - now supports IPv6 addresses for the license service. Using this version should solve your issue.

DISCLAIMER: I work for LogicNP, the developer of CryptoLicensing

Comment: The IPv6 support indeed allows the use of hostnames in the license service. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A 2012 version has just been released. Try with the new version and contact the support again!

What's New in Version 2012:

- NEW: Support for IPv6 address when using customer deployed 
  license service.
- NEW: Much improved exception reporting from license service 
  to client side API.
- NEW: Support for Activation Contexts - supports varying activation 
  counts from the same machine for different features in your 
  software (example, View, Change, Print, etc).
- NEW: Added ready-to-use e-commerce integration pages for FastSpring.
  CHANGE: Heartbeat event is called everytime a heartbeat fails.
- NEW: Improved psf file handling in customer deployed license service.
- NEW: Improved speed when validating licenses.
- NEW: Reduced memory requirements when validating licenses.
- NEW PROPERTY: CryptoLicense.ActivationContext which specifies 
  the context for the activation.